# How to load multiple url in cefsharp using for loop?

Tags: cefsharp

I have url list in a DB.

I am passing all url to browser in foreach loop.But the browser is considering last url only and the page is displaying only for last url but not for previous url which i passed.

How to solve it.?

sample code:

public void GetscreenshotBK(string html,string filepath)
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(filepath);
            string path = @"//td[@class='case']";//span[@class='" + ClassToGet + "']

```
        //Xpath query the document for all matching nodes
        HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(path);

        //Get all the nodes in the node collection
       // List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
        {
            //string path1 = @".//a";//span[@class='" + ClassToGet + "']

            //Xpath query the document for all matching nodes

           IEnumerable<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode> htmlnodevalues = n.Descendants("a");
           foreach (var node in htmlnodevalues)
           {              
               string bkurl = node.GetAttributeValue("href","");
               Browser.Load(bkurl);
               //list.Add(bkurl);
           }}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code you have so far?

Comment: And what do you want to do with the loaded pages?  Just look at them for X seconds?  CefSharp can only look at one page at a time, unless you open them in new tabs.

Comment: i just want to get screen shot with some operation through javascript.

Comment: how to create new tab...

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? They each need different code for screenshots.

Comment: i need solution for winforms..

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to do this job on another thread using Tasks.  Because the main thread with the ChromiumWebBrowser controls needs to be free to load and render the web pages.

Here is an example of how to use the new method:

```
// Take screenshots of 3 web pages, and save the screenshots to C:\testX.png
var takeScreenshots = GetScreenshots(Browser, new[] { "http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com", "http://www.apple.com" });
takeScreenshots.ContinueWith((task) => {
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var bitmap in task.Result)
        bitmap.Save(@"C:\test" + (i++).ToString() + ".png");
});
takeScreenshots.Start();
```

You need to add this method to your class:

```
    public Task<List<Bitmap>> GetScreenshots(ChromiumWebBrowser browser, IEnumerable<string> urls)
    {
        return new Task<List<Bitmap>>(() => {
            var bitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();

            var screenshotDone = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            EventHandler<FrameLoadEndEventArgs> loaded = null;
            loaded = (s, e) => {
                // Start a new thread so CefSharp can finish loading and rendering the page.
                if (e.IsMainFrame && e.Url != "about:blank") {
                    new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                        bitmaps.Add(ControlSnapshot.Snapshot(browser));

                        screenshotDone.Set();
                    }).Start();
                }
            };

            browser.FrameLoadEnd += loaded;

            foreach (string url in urls) {
                // Wait until page finished loading and take a screenshot.
                browser.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
                    browser.Load(url);
                }));

                screenshotDone.WaitOne();
            }

            browser.FrameLoadEnd -= loaded;

            return bitmaps;
        });
    }
```

Along with these `using` statements:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

You will also need to add a new file to take the snapshot, `ControlSnapshot.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class ControlSnapshot
{
    public static Bitmap Snapshot(Control c)
    {
        int width = 0, height = 0;
        IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr dc = IntPtr.Zero;
        c.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {
            width = c.ClientSize.Width;
            height = c.ClientSize.Height;
            hwnd = c.Handle;
            dc = GetDC(hwnd);
        }));
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        if (dc != IntPtr.Zero) {
            try {
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
                    IntPtr bdc = g.GetHdc();
                    try {
                        BitBlt(bdc, 0, 0, width, height, dc, 0, 0, TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY);
                    } finally {
                        g.ReleaseHdc(bdc);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, dc);
            }
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdc, int nXDest, int nYDest, int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hdcSrc, int nXSrc, int nYSrc, TernaryRasterOperations dwRop);

    public enum TernaryRasterOperations : uint
    {
        /// <summary>dest = source</summary>
        SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020,
        /// <summary>dest = source OR dest</summary>
        SRCPAINT = 0x00EE0086,
        /// <summary>dest = source AND dest</summary>
        SRCAND = 0x008800C6,
        /// <summary>dest = source XOR dest</summary>
        SRCINVERT = 0x00660046,
        /// <summary>dest = source AND (NOT dest)</summary>
        SRCERASE = 0x00440328,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT source)</summary>
        NOTSRCCOPY = 0x00330008,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT src) AND (NOT dest)</summary>
        NOTSRCERASE = 0x001100A6,
        /// <summary>dest = (source AND pattern)</summary>
        MERGECOPY = 0x00C000CA,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT source) OR dest</summary>
        MERGEPAINT = 0x00BB0226,
        /// <summary>dest = pattern</summary>
        PATCOPY = 0x00F00021,
        /// <summary>dest = DPSnoo</summary>
        PATPAINT = 0x00FB0A09,
        /// <summary>dest = pattern XOR dest</summary>
        PATINVERT = 0x005A0049,
        /// <summary>dest = (NOT dest)</summary>
        DSTINVERT = 0x00550009,
        /// <summary>dest = BLACK</summary>
        BLACKNESS = 0x00000042,
        /// <summary>dest = WHITE</summary>
        WHITENESS = 0x00FF0062,
        /// <summary>
        /// Capture window as seen on screen.  This includes layered windows
        /// such as WPF windows with AllowsTransparency="true"
        /// </summary>
        CAPTUREBLT = 0x40000000
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sanjay I'm confused... you said you needed a solution for WinForms.

Comment: @Sanjay Perhaps you should test this and and see if it works for you, accept the answer, and then post a new question for a console solution, as it will be completely different.